# No network in Waydroid: network is unreachable

Tags: networking, arch-linux, android, lxc, emulators

I've followed [Waydroid arch-wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Waydroid#Installation) and have installed `waydroid`, `binder_linux-dkms` and `waydroid-image-gapps`.

When I run waydroid it works perfectly except for the network part.

I do have new interfaces on host machine:

```
30: waydroid0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.240.1/24 brd 192.168.240.255 scope global waydroid0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe00:1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
31: vethbrQLNw@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master waydroid0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:3e:17:46:42:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::fc3e:17ff:fe47:4295/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

but I don't have properly configured network interfaces in `waydroid shell`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if31: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:f9:d3:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::fba7:3c32:8e2f:857/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So when I try to ping `1.1.1.1` I catch an error: `connect: Network is unreachable`. And I have no network inside wayland.

I don't have ufw or firewalld installed.

I've tried:

1. Restart `waydroid-container.service`
2. Stop `nftables.service`
3. Restart `iptables.service`

P.S. I have following in journalctl:

```
окт 27 15:16:53 nous dnsmasq[139035]: started, version 2.87 cachesize 150
окт 27 15:16:53 nous dnsmasq[139035]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-UBus i18n IDN2 DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP con>
окт 27 15:16:53 nous dnsmasq-dhcp[139035]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.240.2 -- 192.168.240.254, lease time 1h
окт 27 15:16:53 nous dnsmasq-dhcp[139035]: DHCP, sockets bound exclusively to interface waydroid0
окт 27 15:16:53 nous dnsmasq[139035]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
окт 27 15:16:53 nous dnsmasq[139035]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#53
окт 27 15:16:53 nous dnsmasq[139035]: read /etc/hosts - 148944 addresses
```

(127.0.0.1 is because I have unbound installed)

`waydroid log` output:

```
(138954) [15:16:45] % chmod 666 -R /dev/binder
(138954) [15:16:45] % chmod 666 -R /dev/anbox-vndbinder
(138954) [15:16:45] % chmod 666 -R /dev/anbox-hwbinder
(138954) [15:16:45] Container manager is waiting for session to load
(139008) [15:16:52] Save session config: /var/lib/waydroid/session.cfg
(139008) [15:16:52] UserMonitor service is not even started
(139008) [15:16:52] Clipboard service is not even started
(138954) [15:16:52] % /usr/lib/waydroid/data/scripts/waydroid-net.sh start
vnic is waydroid0
(138954) [15:16:53] % mount /usr/share/waydroid-extra/images/system.img /var/lib/waydroid/rootfs
(138954) [15:16:53] % mount -o remount,ro /usr/share/waydroid-extra/images/system.img /var/lib/waydroid/rootfs
(138954) [15:16:53] % mount /usr/share/waydroid-extra/images/vendor.img /var/lib/waydroid/rootfs/vendor
(138954) [15:16:53] % mount -o remount,ro /usr/share/waydroid-extra/images/vendor.img /var/lib/waydroid/rootfs/vendor
(138954) [15:16:53] % mount -o bind /var/lib/waydroid/waydroid.prop /var/lib/waydroid/rootfs/vendor/waydroid.prop
(138954) [15:16:53] Save config: /var/lib/waydroid/waydroid.cfg
(138954) [15:16:53] % mount -o bind /home/user/.local/share/waydroid/data /var/lib/waydroid/data
(138954) [15:16:53] % chmod 777 -R /dev/ashmem
(138954) [15:16:53] % chmod 777 -R /dev/dri
(138954) [15:16:53] % chmod 777 -R /dev/fb0
(138954) [15:16:53] % chmod 777 -R /dev/video3
(138954) [15:16:53] % chmod 777 -R /dev/video2
(138954) [15:16:53] % chmod 777 -R /dev/video1
(138954) [15:16:53] % chmod 777 -R /dev/video0
(138954) [15:16:53] % lxc-start -P /var/lib/waydroid/lxc -F -n waydroid -- /init
(138954) [15:16:53] New background process: pid=139115, output=background
(138954) [15:16:53] Save session config: /var/lib/waydroid/session.cfg
(139008) [15:17:02] waydroidusermonitor: Received transaction: 1
(139008) [15:17:02] Android with user 0 is ready
(146313) [15:40:48] % tail -n 60 -F /var/lib/waydroid/waydroid.log
(146313) [15:40:48] *** output passed to waydroid stdout, not to this log ***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround one can disable NFT usage (otherwise network will be unusable). Which is by some reason is enabled by default (whereas there is a [commit](https://github.com/waydroid/waydroid/commit/22f671bf0520df68fc6b3cf106e1fc97f462da86) with disabling it).

In case of Arch-linux one should modify `/usr/lib/waydroid/data/scripts/waydroid-net.sh` and ensure there is a line:

```
LXC_USE_NFT=false
```

Answer (score 2):

The `waydroid-net.sh` script has changed again so that more patches are needed to

- Disable `nftables`
- Disable `iptables-legacy` and `ip6tables-legacy`

It can be done using a command like this:

```
sudo sed -i~ -E 's/=.\$\(command -v (nft|ip6?tables-legacy).*/=/g' \
     /usr/lib/waydroid/data/scripts/waydroid-net.sh
```

You might also need to restart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart waydroid-container.service
```

Tested with Waydroid 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.